# Custom Seekbar with TextViews

Tags: android, textview, seekbar

I'm hoping to make a rather complicated CustomSeekBar. The tutorials I have found aren't helping me all that much and this is new ground for me.

I'm aiming for something that looks like this: https://morgazmo99-yahoo-com.tinytake.com/sf/MjIwMjM2XzEzNzI5MzQ

I need all the getting, setting, listening and updating code to be contained in my CustomSeekBar class. textViewA and textViewB should be updated automatically by the overridden onProgressChanged method, although each will also need an OnClickListener to add extra data to those views..

I would imagine I'm close, but I don't know exactly how to encapsulate the views into my CustomSeekBar class. I'm getting NPEs when trying to set the TextViews and I understand basically why, but I'm sure I want the CustomSeekBar component to manage those TextViews.

I'm really just looking for help in how to correctly update the TextViews from OnProgressChanged in my custom class. Code is as follows:

My XML so far works looks about right..

```
<RelativeLayout

            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView

    android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Center of Gravity"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/seekbar_margin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/seekbar_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp" />

<com.sample.myapp.CustomSeekBar

    android:id="@+id/customseekBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTitle"
    android:progressDrawable="@android:color/transparent"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="50"/>

<TextView

    android:id="@+id/textViewA"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="A"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/customseekBar"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/seekbar_margin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/seekbar_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/seekbar_text_padding"
    android:clickable="true"/>

<TextView

    android:id="@+id/textViewB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="B"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/customseekBar"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/seekbar_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/seekbar_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/seekbar_text_padding"
    android:clickable="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And I do have a CustomSeekBar class which is getting there:

```
package com.sample.myapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class CustomSeekBar extends SeekBar implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

private Rect rect;
private Paint paint;
private int seekbar_height, textViewAPercentage, textViewBPercentage;
private String textViewTitleText, textViewAText, textViewBText;;

private TextView textViewA, textViewB, textViewTitle;

public CustomSeekBar(Context context) {

    super(context);
    setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

}

public CustomSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    super(context, attrs);
    setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    rect = new Rect();
    paint = new Paint();
    seekbar_height = 6;

}

public CustomSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {

    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

}

public void setTextViewTitleText(String string) {
    this.textViewTitleText = string;
}

public String getTextA() {
    return textViewAText;
}

public void setTextA(String string) {
    this.textViewAText = string;
}

public String getTextB() {
    return textViewBText;
}

public void setTextB(String string) {
    this.textViewBText = string;
}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

    int seekBarMax = seekBar.getMax();
    textViewAPercentage = (seekBarMax / progress) * 100;
    textViewBPercentage = ((seekBarMax - progress) / seekBarMax) * 100;

    String A, B;

    if (textViewAText != null) A = String.valueOf(textViewAPercentage) + "\n" + textViewAText;
    else A = String.valueOf(textViewAPercentage);

    if (textViewBText != null) B = String.valueOf(textViewBPercentage) + "\n" + textViewBText;
    else B = String.valueOf(textViewBPercentage);

    textViewA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewA);
    textViewB = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewB);

    textViewA.setText(A);
    textViewB.setText(B);

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}

@Override
protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    rect.set(0 + getThumbOffset(), (getHeight() / 2) - (seekbar_height / 2), getWidth() - getThumbOffset(), (getHeight() / 2) + (seekbar_height / 2));
    paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
    if (this.getProgress() > 50) {

        rect.set(getWidth() / 2,  (getHeight() / 2) - (seekbar_height / 2), getWidth() / 2 + (getWidth() / 100) * (getProgress() - 50), getHeight() / 2 + seekbar_height / 2));

        paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);

    }

    if (this.getProgress() < 50) {

        rect.set(getWidth() / 2 - ((getWidth() / 100) * (50 - getProgress())), (getHeight() / 2) - (seekbar_height / 2), getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2 + (seekbar_height / 2));

        paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);

    }

    super.onDraw(canvas);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code

```
interface iSeekChangeListener {
   public void onChange(String a, String b);
}
```

implement iSeekChangeListener to your activity class and override onChange() as follows

```
 @Override
    public void onChange(String a, String b) {

        textViewA.setText(a);
        textViewB.setText(b);
    }
```

in your CustomSeekBar class set the listener

```
  public void setListener(iSeekChangeListener customSeekActivty) {

        this.customSeekListener = customSeekActivty;
    }
```

in your Activity you need to set the listener

```
customSeekBar.setListener(this);
```

in onProgressChange() of your CustomSeekBar

```
if (customSeekListener != null)
            customSeekListener.onChange(A, B);
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know a lot about Interfaces, so it looks like I've got a bit of reading to do. This looks like it will accomplish what I'm trying to do nicely, thanks again.